# A dependency autowired correctly in constructor gets null later on automatically for same Service object with KafkaListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reflection, spring-kafka

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
   //configurations
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {
private Dep dependency;

@Autowired
public KafkaConsumer(Dep dep){
this.dependency = dep;
}

@KafkaListener(topics = "Kafka_Example", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void consume(String message) {
    System.out.println("Consumed message: " + message);//dependency null here
}
```

The dependency is properly autowired when constructor is called. But later on when consume method is called by spring kafka listener then dependency is null. Both times the object of Kafka consumer is the same. Dep is a @Service class with a basic print method.
How is this possible?

But when I add another containerfactory provider method it works and the dependency is not null.

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> customKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

using this as containerFactory works.

What changed?

Comment: Can you please share your `Dep.class`

Comment: Updated the question with Dep class. I don't think it has anything to do with it though. It has something to do with default kafka container factory implementation i think

Comment: May you share a simple project on GitHub to let us reproduce and play? Thanks

Comment: +1 - I am not aware of anything in the framework that would cause this? Is it possible you are using `Mockito.mock()` for the listener class? If you want to use `Mockito` with the listener, you must use `spy()` not `mock()`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I faced the same problem - where I could see the dependency injected in `@PostConstruct` (if field injected) or inside constructor (if constructor injected), but when inside `@KafkaListener` annotated method, injected field was null. 
After hours of debugging, I realised that `@KafkaListener` annotated method was *private*. Do you know the reason/mechanism behind this behaviour?

Comment: I think this deserves an individual SO thread with much more info